# arm g++ does not link the libstdc++

Tags: g++, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile one application to arm based board. I use g++ for development. During loading to the board I tried to cross compile using the arm tool chain (I use arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++). It gives compilation error "undefined reference to std::basic_string", if I copy the path static library libstdc++.a to my default libs path it compiles, but if I copy the dyanamic libstdc++.so lib it shows same error.

I also did $ln -s /croostool chain pathtolib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14 libstdc++.so.

How to properly link the dynamic libs?

Actually if it is C++ means it should automatically link to the  libstdc++, right?

Comment: What platform are you compiling on?  Where did you get your toolchain from, or did you compile it yourself?

Comment: I am compiling on linux , I downloaded from the arm site

Comment: Do `echo $PATH` and post the output. What is the path to the toolchain directory? Do `ls` of the toolchain `bin` directory and post the output. Post the compilation command. This is almost certainly an environment variable problem.

Comment: I am running my application using makefile in the make file I set CXX = /usr/local/arm4/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-c+++  and ls out put is arm-none-linux-gnueabi-addr2line  arm-none-linux-gnueabi-elfedit    arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gdbtui   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar         arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++        arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gprof    arm-none-linux-gnueabi-readelf
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-as         arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc        arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld       arm-none-linux-gnueabi-size
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-c++      arm-none-linux-gnueabi-sprite